# Calcualted field for created date -today not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to make a field to show how many days it has been since this item was created.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Created]),"",TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-[Created])
```

Above is the formula used and below is my result displays:

1. 1 day created 4 days ago
2. 0 day created today
3. 1 day created 5 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DATEDIF(Created,TODAY(),"d")
```

Take a look at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) for more info about calculated column formula

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the following formula:**

`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))-DATEVALUE(TEXT(Created,"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

[image]

[image]